# Storing form data in the database

Tags: django, django-views

I can't figure out how to store a simple form in the database. I think I'm quite close but there is probably something wrong in my views.py. Here is my code, any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (also on [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/836003/))

```
# models.py
class IngredienceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Ingredience Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# forms.py
class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

# views.py
@login_required
def newCategory(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.user.username
        cform = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        if cform.is_valid():
            formInstance = cform.save(commit = False)
            formInstance.user = username
            formInstance.name = cform.cleaned_data['name']
            formInstance =  IngredienceCategory.objects.filter(name=formInstance.name, user=formInstance.user)
            formInstance.save()
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('new-category/')
    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    context = {'form': form}

    return render_to_response('new-category.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# new-category.html
<h3>Insert New Category</h3>
<form action="/" method="post" id="food-form">{% csrf_token %} 
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="foodForm" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line below is not useful at it current position. That command will perform a database query and assign the result as a queryset, before you have saved the form data.

```
formInstance =  IngredienceCategory.objects.filter(name=formInstance.name, user=formInstance.user)
```

**This should work:**

With cform as a normal Form:

```
if cform.is_valid():
    formInstance = IngredienceCategory(user=request.user, cform.cleaned_data['name'])
    formInstance.save()
```

If cform had been a ModelForm you could do:

```
if cform.is_valid():
    formInstance = cform.save(commit=False)
    formInstance.user = request.user
    formInstance.save()
```

I do recommend you to check out [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) since it will build the cleaning functionality based on your model.

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit from ModelForm

from django.forms import ModelForm
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = IngredienceCategory

Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ for how to render form and save it to database.

Comment: is it required to use ModelForm if one wants to store form data in the database? I wanted to try this approach (without ModelForm).

Comment: formInstance = cform.save(commit = False) ... save method is available in ModelForms only ... "With these models, the ModelForm subclasses above would be roughly equivalent to this (the only difference being the save() method" from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Just try it with ModelForm. You can also hide the fields that you don't want to render as part of HTML Form. Without model forms, you need to manually save it to database by creating an instance of the IngredienceCategory. So extract data from request.POST and created an instance of IngredienceCategory, request.user should allow for extracting user reference and you can save the instance.